# What excel formula would i need to you to count how many times something happens between a time range of 11pm and 3am

Tags: excel, formula

What excel formula would i need to you to count how many times something happens between a time range of 11pm and 3am. I am counting up how many patients are discharge during time ranges of 7a-11a, 11a-3p, 3p-7p, 7p-11p, 11p-3a, and 3a-7a.

This is the formula that i am using for the time range of 7a-11a.
=COUNTIFS(F2:F321,">=07:00",F2:F321, "<=10:59")

It works for everytime range except the 11p-3a.

I have tried to count the range from 2300-2359 and then 0000-0300 and add them, i have removed the "=" before 0300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break your time span from 11 PM to midnight and from midnight to 3 AM:

```
=COUNTIFS(F2:F321,">=23:00",F2:F321,"<=23:59")+COUNTIFS(F2:F321,">=00:00",F2:F321,"<=03:00")
```

Comment: Thank you! There must have been a user error on my end because i had entered that formula and it was not giving me an answer